# Convert one byte in to two int values separated after 4 digits

Tags: java, binary, byte

I have this `byte`/`int` `0001 0010` (`18`). I need to split this `byte`/`int` into

`0001 0000` (`16`) and
`0000 0010` (`2`).

How can I do that in Java?

Comment: this is your professor. how many times have i said to use StackOverflow after you've come up with something?

Comment: hahaha :) Nothing can go bad than this. @Freak2000 - Hide out somewhere. You got caught. ;)

Comment: Haha, maybe I should have checked the comments before posting my answer

Comment: Nice to see that professors suggest asking for clarification on SO, when in problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is bitwise AND. `-16` is `11110000` in binary, `15` is `00001111`.

```
public static byte[] split(byte input) {
    byte[] output = new byte[2];

    output[0] = (byte) (input & -16);
    output[1] = (byte) (input & 15);

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Instead of 15 and -16 you can also use `0x0f` and `(byte)0xf0`.

Comment: Or `0b11110000` and `0b00001111` if you're using Java 7.

Comment: @Jesper: More than 50% of users are still on Java6. I don't use any of that stuff yet (`<>`), and won't until more people migrate. [Here are some statistics](http://www.statowl.com/java.php?mes=ndd)

Comment: @durron597 It was just a tip for those that do use Java 7, not intended as criticism of your solution. No need to argue; I don't need to be convinced of anything.

Comment: @Jesper: Sorry this is a hot button issue for me, I didn't mean to take it out on you, I feel like every 3rd thing I post someone on this site is always telling me to use some Java7 bell/whistle.